# Asp.Net Core Identity - simple Authorization without Roles table

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to develop a simple user authorization mechanism for my application, without using a specific Roles table.

The User entity has a simple Role enum property, and I would like to properly decorate the `Authorize` attribute on some controllers.

Maybe I'm missing something here, but how can I let the framework know what is the role of the user when or immediately after he logs in

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(usr, pwd, false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

and then use the `Authorize` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [UserManager.AddClaimAsync(TUser, Claim) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.addclaimasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1) could help add the specified claim to the user, you can try the following code snippet to achieve your requirement.

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.Email);

    var userRole = CustomMethod_FindUserRole(Input.Email);

    await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));

    //...

    await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);


    //...
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this should be the accepted answer, but maybe you should specify that you have to implement properly AddClaimAsync

Comment: Does the `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` by default add any additional claims?

Answer (score 0):

You can add claim of Role to particular user using ProfileService of identity server. where you need to add

```
claims.Add(new Claim("Role","Admin"));
```

Also you need to implement policy in your starup.cs as

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AdminCheck", policy =>
                          policy.RequireClaim("Role", "Admin"));
    });
```

And on your action method or controller you need to put decorator as

```
[Authorize(Policy = "AdminCheck")]
public class VacationController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult VacationBalance()
    {
    }
}
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to do something similar, but i don't understand where claims should be passed. After adding the role claim, how should I use the claims object?